# Pocketsphinx french does not work on my buildroot embedded device

Tags: buildroot, pocketsphinx

I try to install Pocketsphinx in French on a Buildroot embedded device. So I dowloaded the default french language model: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/French/

I tried several times to make pocketsphinx works using command line on the embedded device, but it failed each time. I learned that it could be caused by the huge size of my dictionary (~ 100 000 words, called fr.dict), so I created a much smaller dictionary of 100 words (called fr-test.dict). But it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

I use the pocketsphinx_continuous command line. I defined a hmm, a dictionary and a language model which are pulled out from this folder :

Three differents hmm:

```
cmusphinx-fr-5.2 
cmusphinx-fr-ptm-5.2 
cmusphinx-fr-ptm-8khz-5.2
```

Two dictionaries:

```
fr.dict
fr-test.dict
```

And three language models

```
fr.lm.dmp
fr-small.lm.bin
fr-phone.lm.dmp
```

The first two parameters doesn't seem to change anything. However, the thrid one does change the error messages I receive.

With the first lm (fr.lm.dmp) the complete log are:

```
# pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plug:pcm.mic -inmic yes -hmm /mnt/usb/sphinx-f
rench/cmusphinx-fr-5.2 -lm /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.lm.dmp -dict /mnt/usb/sphin
x-french/
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+00
-allphone
-allphone_ci            no              no
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-01
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+01
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-48
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+00
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    current         current
-cmninit                8.0             8.0
-compallsen             no              no
-debug                                  0
-dict                                   /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-08
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-29
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm                                    /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold          1               1.000000e+00
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               22
-lm                                     /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.lm.dmp
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+00
-logfn
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.300000e+02
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-29
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-07
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             512
-nfilt                  40              25
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+00
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-48
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+00
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+04
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-03
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-04
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          dct
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.800000e+03
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          2.0             2.000000e+00
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-04
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-29
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-01
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(152): Reading linear feature transformation from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 101051 * 8 bytes (789 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(804): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 2108
INFO: acmod.c(115): Attempting to use semi-continuous computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: acmod.c(117): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights
INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 2108 senones: 1 features x 8 codewords
INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
INFO: ms_mgau.c(144): The value of topn: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 4099 * 20 bytes (80 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 0, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 0 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 3, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 3 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 36^3 * 2 bytes (91 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(347): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(358): Header doesn't match
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(176): Trying to read LM in arpa format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(69): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(438): Trying to read LM in DMP format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(520): ngrams 1=62304, 2=18541132, 3=23627127
calloc(23627127,16) failed from ngrams_raw.c(278)
```

With the two others, I receive these logs:

```
 # pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plug:pcm.mic -inmic yes -hmm /mnt/usb/sphinx-f
rench/cmusphinx-fr-5.2 -lm /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-phone.lm.dmp -dict /mnt/usb
/sphinx-french/fr.dict
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+00
-allphone
-allphone_ci            no              no
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-01
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+01
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-48
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+00
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    current         current
-cmninit                8.0             8.0
-compallsen             no              no
-debug                                  0
-dict                                   /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.dict
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-08
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-29
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm                                    /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold          1               1.000000e+00
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               22
-lm                                     /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-phone.lm.dmp
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+00
-logfn
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.300000e+02
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-29
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-07
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             512
-nfilt                  40              25
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+00
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-48
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+00
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+04
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-03
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-04
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          dct
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.800000e+03
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          2.0             2.000000e+00
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-04
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-29
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-01
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(152): Reading linear feature transformation from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 101051 * 8 bytes (789 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(804): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 2108
INFO: acmod.c(115): Attempting to use semi-continuous computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: acmod.c(117): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights
INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 2108 senones: 1 features x 8 codewords
INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
INFO: ms_mgau.c(144): The value of topn: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 109102 * 20 bytes (2130 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 105003, allocated 1018 KiB for strings, 1375 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 105003 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 105006, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 3 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 36^3 * 2 bytes (91 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(347): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(358): Header doesn't match
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(176): Trying to read LM in arpa format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(69): No \data\ mark in LM file
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(438): Trying to read LM in DMP format
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(520): ngrams 1=38, 2=1240, 3=23231
INFO: lm_trie.c(473): Training quantizer
INFO: lm_trie.c(481): Building LM trie
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(74): Initializing search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(101): 742 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search channels
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 136
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 12 root, 8 non-root channels, 14 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: continuous.c(307): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Apr 18 2019, AT: 18:26:09

INFO: continuous.c(252): Ready....
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
```

A new "Input overrun" log appear every second. And remember these results does not change with another hmm or a smaller dictionary.

Any idea what is happening and how I can solve the problem ?

Comment: Input overrun means your decoding is too slow to process the data in realtime. You need smaller models or faster CPU. Phone model is for phonetic decoding, you need to use fr-small.lm.dmp. You didn't publish the log with it.

Answer (score 0):

I will give to more information here:

1) When I use the "top" bash command to see the consumption of Pocketsphinx while running it, it return the following:

```
Mem: 292420K used, 717876K free, 552K shrd, 46032K buff, 112032K cached
CPU:   0% usr   3% sys   0% nic  95% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.20 0.64 0.69 1/166 2377
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ %CPU COMMAND
 2061     1 root     S    16520   2%   3% sndnrj -d plug:aec
 2130  2099 root     R    76496   8%   0% /usr/bin/ws-proxyd -i lo -p 7894 -D /u
 2371  2100 root     S    33428   3%   0% pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plug:p
 2271  2099 root     S    19068   2%   0% /usr/bin/ws-proxyd -i lo -p 7895 -D /u
 2276  2099 root     S      99m  10%   0% /usr/bin/node /opt/app/index.js --no-u
 1868     1 root     S     1992   0%   0% /sbin/klogd -n
 1912     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [ksdioirqd/sdio]
 2104  2099 root     S    22140   2%   0% /usr/bin/storaged -v 0
 2073     1 root     S    11796   1%   0% sc-am /etc/sc-am.cfg
 2269  2099 root     S     9952   1%   0% /usr/bin/sc-directive -c /flash/etc/di
 2103  2099 root     S     8028   1%   0% /usr/bin/sc_net
 2099     1 root     S     7448   1%   0% nsm
 2114  2099 root     S     7128   1%   0% /usr/bin/sc-led-matrix -f /dev/i2c-2
 2102  2099 root     S     5144   1%   0% /usr/bin/sysinfod -c /etc/sysinfod/sys
 2119     1 root     S     5096   1%   0% /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u
 2092  2091 www-data S     5064   0%   0% nginx: worker process
 2065     1 root     S     4972   0%   0% pupd -d /dev/spidev32766.0 -f /usr/sha
 2091     1 root     S     4932   0%   0% nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
 2253     1 root     S     3860   0%   0% /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

So I don't think my problem is the CPU.

2) When I use the lm fr-small.lm.bin with the small dictionary of 100 words, it returned the following:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plug:pcm.mic -inmic yes -hmm /mnt/usb/sphinx-f
rench/cmusphinx-fr-5.2 -lm /mnt/usb/sphinx-french./fr-small.lm.bin -dict /mnt/us
b/sphinx-french/fr-test.dict
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+00
-allphone
-allphone_ci            no              no
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-01
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+01
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-48
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+00
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    current         current
-cmninit                8.0             8.0
-compallsen             no              no
-debug                                  0
-dict                                   /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-test.dict
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-08
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-29
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm                                    /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold          1               1.000000e+00
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               22
-lm                                     /mnt/usb/sphinx-french./fr-small.lm.bin
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+00
-logfn
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.300000e+02
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-29
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-07
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             512
-nfilt                  40              25
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+00
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-48
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+00
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+04
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-03
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-04
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          dct
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.800000e+03
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          2.0             2.000000e+00
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-04
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-29
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-01
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(152): Reading linear feature transformation from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 101051 * 8 bytes (789 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(804): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 2108
INFO: acmod.c(115): Attempting to use semi-continuous computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: acmod.c(117): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights
INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 2108 senones: 1 features x 8 codewords
INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
INFO: ms_mgau.c(144): The value of topn: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 4199 * 20 bytes (82 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-test.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 100, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 100 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 103, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 3 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 36^3 * 2 bytes (91 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(347): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(74): Initializing search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(101): 35 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search channels
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 157
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 2 root, 29 non-root channels, 4 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: continuous.c(307): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Apr 18 2019, AT: 18:26:09

INFO: continuous.c(252): Ready....
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
```